Issue with ComboBox in Form Shadcn UI - Unable to Select Values
I'm encountering a problem with the ComboBox component of Shadcn UI when used within a form element. It seems that within this context, I'm unable to select values from the ComboBox.
I'm utilizing the ComboBox component provided by Shadcn UI within a form element of same shadcn UI.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I had same issue, to resolve that you need:
check if some of the parts of library are outdated
npm outdated

then clean cache to update correct version of the part:
npm cache clean --force

and then install part ( as example I had to update those AND OTHER RELATED TO RADIX packages to v1.1.1):
npm install @radix-ui/react-dialog@1.1.1 @radix-ui/react-slot@1.1.0

refresh page, and it should work!
